# How can I capture a portion of the screen during a screen capture

Tags: screen-recorder, obs-studio

I can add a display capture as a source, but can only select the entire monitor. 
 Is there a way to select only a portion of the screen?

1. Add Display Capture

   [image: Add Display Capture]
2. Select Entire Display

   [image: Display Capture Source]

But there's not an option to just select a portion of the screen.  Any tools to do this without doing it in post?

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread on [how to record only a portion of a screen](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/how-to-record-only-a-portion-of-a-screen.70457/), you can:

1. Right click on the Display Source and select **Filters**

   [image: Filters Window]
2. Select Add Filter <kbd>+</kbd> and select **Crop/Pad**

   [image: Add Filter > Crop Pad]
3. You can choose relative or absolute positioning:

   [image: Relative / Absolute Positioning]

---

**Note**: If your display now only takes up part of your canvas (like the following image)

[image: Cropped image partial canvas]

Remember to either:

1. Right Click on the Display Source and select **Resize output (source size)**.
2. *Or* go to the Settings > Video > and update the **Base (Canvas) Resolution**.